# Error on web.Webs.Add, Invalid Characters

Tags: development, error, ssom

I'm currently trying to create a Sub Web on a Site.
The problem I'm faced with is that for some reason I'm getting an strange error message.

> Additional information:
>   "`http://dev-env/sites/site/subsite/`" contains invalid
>   character ':'.

As far as I can tell I'm not using any invalid characters.

```
elevatedWeb.Webs.Add(strWebUrl, title, strDescription, nLCID, WebTemplate, uniquePerms, bConvertIfThere);
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are passing the full url instead of relative url

Replace

```
http://dev-env/sites/site/subsite/
```

With

```
subsite
```

i.e

```
elevatedWeb.Webs.Add(title, title, strDescription, nLCID, WebTemplate, uniquePerms, bConvertIfThere);
```